# How to protect .asp files from editing?

Tags: security, asp-classic

My website was hacked and my homepage was changed again and again. Is there any tools or any ASP sources can protect it from editing?

I set the attributes hidden, read and system to the index.asp files, well, it was changed by the hacker again.

Notes:

- My site was hosted in a shared server
- My website was hacked by a china chopper before
- I have cleaned server hidden asp files..

Comment: I don't see how you would be able to do that - once the hacker has control of the server they will be able to do anything they want to your files. Perhaps you could set up a monitor which will at least alert you if the files are changed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about software development

Comment: Find a better host, good chance the hacker got access to the server itself by hacking other side and now have full access over all sites hosted there. Also learn about all kinds of Injections (SQL, XSS) and make sure you're protected. There is no magic solution here.

Comment: Hi ,i think they just own a webshell ,and has not control the server yet.your suggestion is nice,and do you have monitors? since it is a share server,and i even do not have a remote account to manage my sites..

Comment: Hi shadow,i wish i can learn more about the injections.and but for sure it need a lot of time. i do a small business online,and i am searching for a better way to just keep the hackers from changing my homepage,actually they just put all kinds of backlinks at the bottom..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it bluntly, secure your server it will stop the hackers editing your pages :)

It sounds like your server has been compromised at a higher level, if this is a hosted solution (by a 3rd party company) they need to fix their servers. Unfortunately I've seen smaller hosting companies never fix the problem and just replace the files back and blame "poor coding" when the problem is actually "stupid system admins that don't know what they are doing". If this is the case, move to a different host. If this is your machine and you are hosting it, rebuild the entire machine it sounds like it has been compromised.

Answer (score 0):

For your site 1st you need to check some security measure like there may chance that your web site vulnerabilities . With following attack like **SQLinjection, Blind SQl , XSS, Oracle Padding Attack, DOT-NET-Nuke** etc .

2nd thing as @silver said may be your host is responsible for all this thing like many time on IIS there is major security issue if your other site which is hosted in the server is having some vulnerabilities so attacker or hacker can access of the server throw PHP-Shells and Some ASP or ASPX shells. So for this issue you need to choice the good host :)